# Can my dotnet core web service count the number of calls made to it?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core

I have a dotnet core 1.1 web API.  I know *someone* is keeping track of how many calls to it get made, because it's hosted in Azure and I can see a graph of it on that app's Overview page.

What I want to do is have some kind of /stats endpoint in the API proper which will report the number of calls to the API, the number of HTTP-200 returns, and the number of non-200 returns.

Is there a built-in way to get this data from inside a controller in that same API?  I mean, I could create a middleware which increments a counter before calling "await _next.Invoke(context)", but it seems like I'm reinventing the wheel.

Thoughts on this?

> Edit:  I know (hat tip Danny Chen) that with Application Insights I can get this information from Azure console.  I'd settle for being able to query Azure for that programmatically... Basically I want to be able to use this data in Zabbix or other system as well as Azure console.

Answer (score 3):

[Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/) is exactly what you want, in fact much more than "counting failure responses". The feature you want can be achieved using the [profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler).

**UPDATE** Since you deployed the application in different cloud platforms and wanted to "get the data" from a third application, you have two choices:

Solution 1: Without modifying your application, adding server-less triggers to the cloud platforms. For Azure, use [Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). For AWS, use [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). The good thing is you don't need to modify the application, which means your web application is focus on business. Let the professionals do the monitoring. The "disadvantage" is you need to add different implementations for different cloud platforms, which IMO is not that bad because it's a one-time job and we have only a few cloud providers in the world.

Solution 2(not recommended): Adding a middleware to your web app, count the requests in this middleware and make its data accessible by Zabbix(for example, an web API). It's "platform compatible", but what if there is a new feature saying "count how many requests are for the old-version api"? Now go and modify the code, and re-deploy your application! Oh there is a bug in the middleware? OMG the whole application is affected...

Comment: Mr Chen, thanks for the tip on AI.  Here's the thing though...  I wanted to have the web service itself able to discover this information and serve it from a controller, because I have apps in Azure and AWS and I want Zabbix to be able to contact both types of apps with the same signature (ie https://host/servicename/status).  Maybe I could have my controller interrogate AWS...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionFilter.

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes
    }
}
```

I hope it's not that middlewareabout which you thought about.
Simple make static variable in counter in that, or save it to some file.
Then add filter to specific methods/controllers or register it as global:

```
services.AddMvc(
    config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new GlobalFilter(SampleActionFilter));
        });
```

Comment: Mr Zmuda, thanks for the tip.  I've gone back and forth about using a filter or middleware (some interesting thoughts here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582758/asp-net-core-middleware-vs-filters ).