# C# - Keep real time count of endpoint calls

Tags: c#, api, count, real-time, endpoint

I have a endpoint like so in my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Result> myEndpoint() 
{
   ...
}
```

The code will be hosted on multiple servers and I need to keep a real time count of how many times it is being called across all servers.

Originally I figured a distributed cache with Redis might be useful, but I could run into issues if multiple servers grabbed the same number from the cache and manipulated it at the same time. The numbers would be off if that happened.

Is there a good way to keep a real time count for any given endpoint?

Comment: Do you need a constant and accurate count or is it good enough if your count is [eventually consistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency)? Each server would keep track of the number of times its endpoint had been called and would periodically push that count to your central point of truth before resetting its own count. The central point is responsible for adding all the individual counts to the running total and could return the current total to each server if you need an estimate available from each.

Comment: There are api gateways for specific reasons. there might be some existing middlewares for counting the calls to specific end point. I have heard about application insights but haven't used. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229605/can-my-dotnet-core-web-service-count-the-number-of-calls-made-to-it

Comment: I think the best solution depends on why you need the count. As pointed out by D M and Kamran. If your goal is to use the counts for some real-time action (such as rate limiting) then using some API gateway would be the best approach. If you are just interested in historical analysis then you can look into something like https://opentelemetry.io/ which allows you track anything happening in your app (assuming you have some place to store the telemetry and run analytics on it)

Comment: @emagers I need it in real time to deal with rate limiting (I can't allow more than a certain number of call per second, regardless of who calls it), I was asked for it to be in the API code, which clearly is not going to work the way I want. And I guess the API gateway is where this would need to live.

Comment: Application Insights gives you this (almost) for free.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way in .NET 7. You can use RateLimmiting middleware to do that for you.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/rate-limit?view=aspnetcore-7.0

It will allow you to control the rate limits on each endpoint. You can specify multiple limit types and different limits/logic for different endpoints.