# Asp.Net Core Web app: Global exception handling using IExceptionFilter vs custom middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Asp.Net Core supports two ways to do global exception handling for a Web Application, implementing IExceptionFilter or by creating custom middleware. Is there any advantage of one over the other? Most references I see are for creating custom middleware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net core middleware vs filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582758/asp-net-core-middleware-vs-filters)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#exception-filters) explains the main differences between these two approaches. It states that exception filters:

> - Handle unhandled exceptions that occur in Razor Page or controller creation, [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding), action filters, or action methods.
> - Do **not** catch exceptions that occur in resource filters, result filters, or MVC result execution.

There's even advice for when to use middleware and when to use exception filters:

> Exception filters:
>
> - Are good for trapping exceptions that occur within actions.
> - Are not as flexible as error handling middleware.
>
> Prefer middleware for exception handling. Use exception filters only where error handling *differs* based on which action method is called. For example, an app might have action methods for both API endpoints and for views/HTML. The API endpoints could return error information as JSON, while the view-based actions could return an error page as HTML.

Comment: Microsoft states that "e API endpoints could return error information as JSON, while the view-based actions could return an error page as HTML." but doesn't explain how we would make the distinction. Any ideas?