# Catching exceptions in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have seen multiple ways of catching exceptions in ASP.NET MVC Core, but I need to understand why what I did doesn't work as I expected.

I added the following:

```
public abstract class GenericActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    protected readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (await OnBeforeActionExecutionAsync(context))
        {
            var executed = await next();

            if (executed.Exception != null && !executed.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                await OnExceptionAsync(context, executed.Exception);
            }
            else
            {
                await OnAfterActionExecutionAsync(context);
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual Task<bool> OnBeforeActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    public virtual Task OnAfterActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual Task OnExceptionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
public class ExceptionFilter : GenericActionFilter
{
    public IntegrationScenarioSettings Settings { get; set; }


    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        context.Result = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = Settings.ApiExecutionExceptionMessage,
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable
        };

        //outputs to endpoint.log
        Logger.Error(ex);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The underlying code in the action is throwing an exception and rather then seeing the 503, I still the 500.

What is it I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to inform the ASP.NET Core MVC pipeline that you've handled an exception, you need to set [`ActionExecutedContext.ExceptionHandled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutedcontext.exceptionhandled?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ActionExecutedContext_ExceptionHandled) to `true`. Because you don't have this in the code you've shown, the ASP.NET Core MVC pipeline uses its own error-handling logic to convert your (what it thinks is) unhandled exception into the 500 response.

Now - this property exists on [`ActionExecutedContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutedcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and not on [`ActionExecutingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) (which you're using in your code). This makes sense, as `ActionExecutingContext` represents the state *before* the action runs and `ActionExecutedContext` represents the state *after* the action runs. This means you're going to need the following set of changes:

1. Update your `OnExceptionAsync` function to take `ActionExecutedContext` instead of `ActionExecutingContext`.
2. Update the call to `OnExceptionAsync`, providing `executed` instead of `context`. Whilst you're here, you could also collapse the method parameters down to *just* `executed` (I'll show this in the code, below).
3. Set `context.ExceptionHandled` to `true` once you've, well, handled the exception. :)

I've taken the code from your question, stripped out some of the code that isn't relevant to the issue and applied these changes, which I've called out with the corresponding numbers from above:

```
public abstract class GenericActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (await OnBeforeActionExecutionAsync(context))
        {
            var executed = await next();

            if (executed.Exception != null && !executed.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                await OnExceptionAsync(executed); // #2.
            }
            else
            {
                // NOTE: You might want to use executed here too.
                await OnAfterActionExecutionAsync(context);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    public virtual Task OnExceptionAsync(ActionExecutedContext context) // #1.
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```
public class ExceptionFilter : GenericActionFilter
{    
    public override Task OnExceptionAsync(ActionExecutedContext context) // #1, #2.
    {
        Logger.Error(context.Exception); // #2 (single parameter).

        context.Result = new ContentResult { ... };
        context.ExceptionHandled = true; // #3.

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've deliberately stayed away from suggesting alternatives here, as you've already acknowledged that you've seen these and are more interested in *why* your approach isn't working. I've answered something on that subject before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981785/asp-net-core-web-app-global-exception-handling-using-iexceptionfilter-vs-custom/47981919#47981919).