# ExceptionHandling Middleware vs filter aspnetcore webapi 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I wonder if somebody can clarify this one .I find the usage confusing.

Both links and video did NOT answer my question

I am aware of links like
[asp.net core middleware vs filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582758/asp-net-core-middleware-vs-filters)

and even a video about it

However for the purpose of the webApi alone does it make sense to implement both?

My understanding is that they cover different parts of the system.

Is there a project (github)or link that clearly explain how to use them.

Can I use both in the same webApi ?

Any samples?

thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use both in your project but if your project only has MVC APIs and you are concerned only about capturing unhandled exceptions from your code then using a filter or middleware won't make much of difference and I would say use a filter.

However, if you are more concerned about errors that may occur outside of the MVC context or your code, for example, you want to capture an error in the Routing middleware then use a middleware.

Another major reason to use a filter would be that you get the MVC context in the filter. So if you have a logic like that if the exception occurred when the call was made to POST /orders then you want to log a different exception and if it was in another action then do something else. In such a case use a Filter.

In summary, I try to follow a flow like this

**AM I CONCERNED ABOUT ERRORS IN THE ASP.NET FRAMEWORK** - Use Middleware

**AM I CONCERNED ONLY ABOUT ERRORS IN MY CODE** - Use Filter

**DO I NEED TO CAPTURE THE GLOBAL ERRORS IN THE ASP.NET FRAMEWORK AS WELL AS I HAVE UNIQUE LOGIC BASED ON WHERE THE ERROR OCCURRED** - Use Both